# Set Select value for HTML using formgroup

Tags: html, angular, typescript, formgroups

On basis of Json Data , i have to iterate a selection of radio buttons out of which only one can be selected.

JSONDATA = Observable.of({
    items: [
    itemId:1,
    itemId:2,
    itemId:3
    ]})

Formgroup looks like below consisting of users selected itemId:

```
 this.myform = this.fb.group({
      mydata: ''
    });
```

The HTML iterated over is as below:

```
 <div *ngFor="let item of (items$ | async); index as i; first as first">
            <input type="radio" id="{{item.itemId}}" name="test" value="{{item.itemId}}"  [formControl]="myform.controls.mydata" >
    </div>
```

In a particular scenario there is a requirement that if json data has only one itemId in it, then the radio button has to be preselected and form should automatically be set with that value and form gets VALID.

I was able to set the data with formgroup setValue using:

```
this.myform.setValue(mydata , 1)
```

But in this scenario the form state changes to valid but in HTML, the radio button was not selected. So i tried to achieve that with appending selected to radio button

But this also gives an error for template parsing.

So basically i want the radio button to be preselected if array has only one item.

Comment: Its hard to understand you you want. Can you be more specific and if possible create the situation on stackblitz?

Comment: edited my question again